# Using #define to determine ios device type

Tags: ios, preprocessor

I'm figuring out how to determine iOS device types and came across this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16319767/440646

The line of question:
`#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`

I read that #define is a preprocessor that get evaluated before compilation, so is the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` statement.

My question is how does the compiler knows which device to compile for, since we'll only get to know which device a user is using during runtime?

Comment: Understand that `#define` defines substitution text.  Wherever you code `IS_IPAD`, the text `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` be substituted in it's place before compilation.  You could accomplish the same test by coding `(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` directly in an `if` statement.  The "macro" defined in the `#define` is just a convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` does not check for a specific device (iPhone 4, iPhone 5, etc) but a device category (iPhone, iPad).

Here is another SO question that shows what the macro does. This will help you understand: [Is it safe to check for UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() to determine if it's an iPhone or iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905603/is-it-safe-to-check-for-ui-user-interface-idiom-to-determine-if-its-an-iphone)